# Checkbox Javascript function not working in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap and have a textfield and a checkbox inside a modal. I'm using javascript to enable the textfield when the checkbox is checked, but when inside the modal it doesn't seem to work.

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <form action="php_add/event.php" method="post">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="checkbox" id="foodBox" class="flat-red foodBox" />
            <input name="food" id="food" disabled>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).getElementById('foodBox').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('food').disabled = !this.checked;
    document.getElementById('food').value = "";
};
```

Why doesn't the function work when the checkbox is inside the modal?

Comment: `document.getElementById` - not `$(document).getElementById`

Comment: When troubleshooting Javascript always check your browser's console, which you can access by pressing F12 for most browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed. This is a bug with event propagation in Bootstrap's Modal events. It fires a "preventDefault", which stops stuff from happening before the modal opens. I found that if you do this AFTER the modal opens, it then works as you would like, but happens fast enough to not be noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing jQuery and native JS syntax.. for native JS:

```
document.getElementById("foodBox").onchange = function() {
    var food = document.getElementById('food');
    food.disabled = !this.checked;
    food.value = "";
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#foodBox").change(function() {
    $("#food").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
    $("#food").val("");
});
```

Comment: I had the first alternative at first, and has changed back now aswell, still not working

Comment: @jahed -- works here: http://jsfiddle.net/59bLnLtv/

Comment: where should I put the jquery? inside the head-tag or in a page-script?

Comment: @jahed -- It's JavaScript - you put it inside `<script>` tags.

Comment: This definitely does not work for me. It's worked before when I didnt use a modal but inside the modal it doesnt work at all